# What better way to design the built-in stats function of a sentence generator?

Tags: javascript, performance, random, dynamically-generated, maintainability

**Context** : a random sentence generator

> 1. the function `generateSentence()` generates random sentences
>    returned as strings (**works fine**)
> 2. the function `calculateStats()` outputs the number of unique
>    strings the above function can theoretically generate (works fine also **in
>    this mockup**, so be sure to read the disclaimer, I don't want to waste your time)
> 3. the function `generateStructure()` and the words lists in
>    `Dictionnary.lists` are constantly growing as time passes

Quick mockup of the main generator function :

```
function generateSentence() {
  var words = [];
  var structure = generateStructure();

  structure.forEach(function(element) {
    words.push(Dictionnary.getElement(element));
  });

  var fullText = words.join(" ");
  fullText = fullText.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + fullText.substring(1);
  fullText += ".";
  return fullText;
}

var Dictionnary = {
  getElement: function(listCode) {
    return randomPick(Dictionnary.lists[listCode]);
  },
  lists: {
    _location: ["here,", "at my cousin's,", "in Antarctica,"],
    _subject: ["some guy", "the teacher", "Godzilla"],
    _vTransitive: ["is eating", "is scolding", "is seeing"],
    _vIntransitive: ["is working", "is sitting", "is yawning"],
    _adverb: ["slowly", "very carefully", "with a passion"],
    _object: ["this chair", "an egg", "the statue of Liberty"],
  }
}

// returns an array of strings symbolizing types of sentence elements
// example : ["_location", "_subject", "_vIntransitive"]
function generateStructure() {
  var str = [];

  if (dice(6) > 5) {// the structure can begin with a location or not
    str.push("_location");
  }

  str.push("_subject");// the subject is mandatory

  // verb can be of either types
  var verbType = randomPick(["_vTransitive", "_vIntransitive"]);
  str.push(verbType);

  if (dice(6) > 5) {// adverb is optional
    str.push("_adverb");
  }

  // the structure needs an object if the verb is transitive
  if (verbType == "_vTransitive") {
    str.push("_object");
  }

  return str;
}

// off-topic warning! don't mind the implementation here,
// just know it's a random pick in the array
function randomPick(sourceArray) {
  return sourceArray[dice(sourceArray.length) - 1];
}

// Same as above, not the point, just know it's a die roll (random integer from 1 to max)
function dice(max) {
  if (max < 1) { return 0; }
  return Math.round((Math.random() * max) + .5);
}
```

At some point I wanted to know how many different unique strings it could output and I wrote something like (again, very simplified) :

```
function calculateStats() {// the "broken leg" function I'm trying to improve/replace
  var total = 0;
  // lines below : +1 to account for 'no location' or 'no adverb'
  var nbOfLocations = Dictionnary.lists._location.length + 1;
  var nbOfAdverbs = Dictionnary.lists._adverb.length + 1;

  var nbOfTransitiveSentences = 
    nbOfLocations *
    Dictionnary.lists._vTransitive.length *
    nbOfAdverbs *
    Dictionnary.lists._object.length;
  var nbOfIntransitiveSentences =
    nbOfLocations *
    Dictionnary.lists._vIntransitive.length *
    nbOfAdverbs;

  total = nbOfTransitiveSentences + nbOfIntransitiveSentences;
  return total;
}
```

*(Side note : don't worry about namespace pollution, type checks on input parameters, or these sort of things, this is assumed to be in a bubble for the sake of example clarity.)*

**Important disclaimer** : This is not about fixing the code I posted. This is a mock-up and it works as it is. The real question is *"As the complexity of possible structures grow in the future, as well as the size and diversity of the lists, what would be a better strategy to calculate stats for these types of random constructions, rather than my clumsy `calculateStats()` function, which is hard to maintain, likely to handle astronomically big numbers*, and prone to errors?"*

* in the real tool, there are 351 120 unique structures at this moment, and for sentences... the total number has exceeded (10 power 80) for some time already.

Comment: You need a more general generator to be able to calculate its complexity more generally.

Comment: @JonasW. The thing is, human languages are full of arbitrary things, the model itself is not general, so being generic here would lead to dramatically reduce the diversity, hence the quality of the tool.

Comment: I thought of some very strictly defined rules, somethig like `dict().maybe(locations).and(subject).and(verb).maybe(somethingElse)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your structure for sentences change quite a lot (it does change in this small example I can't imagine how much does it change in the actual code), I would do something similar to this:

First I will need to save in a way all the possible sentence structures that exist for a given `Dictionary`... Maybe I would create a `Language` object that has a Dictionary as a property, and I could add the possible sentence structures (this part probably could be optimized and find a more procedural way of generating all the possible sentence structures, like a rule engine). **What do you mean by sentence structure**? Well, following your example I will call sentence structure to the next:

```
[ 'location', 'transitive-verb', 'adverb', 'object' ] < - Transitive sentence
[ 'location', 'instransitive-verb', 'adverb' ] <- Intransitive sentence
```

You could probably find a way of generate this structures... or hardcode them.

But... **why do I think that could improve the way you calculate the stats?** Because you minimize the hardcoding of each number of sentences by using a map / reduce operation and make it more extensible.

So... **how?**

Imagine that we have our structures accessible in the global scope or through an object, or in the dictionary itself:

```
// Somewhere in the code
const structures = [
  [ 'location', 'transitive-verb', 'adverb', 'object' ],
  [ 'location', 'instransitive-verb', 'adverb' ] 
];
...
// In this example I just passed it as an argument
function calculateStats(structures) {
  const numberOfCombinations = structures.reduce((total, structure) => {
      // We should calculate the number of combinations a structure has
      const numberOfSentences = structure.reduce((acc, wordType) => {
          // For each word type, we access the list and get the lenght (I am not doing safety checks for any wordType)
          return acc + Dictionary.lists[wordType].length
      }, 0);//Initial accumulator

      return total + numberOfSentences;
  }, 0); // Initial accumulator
  return numberOfCombinations;
}
```

So we would use the power of iterating through different structures instead of hard coding each possible combination, so you basically only need to add structures and your `calculateStats` function shouldn't grow.

If you need to do more complex calculations you would need to change the functions used in the reducers.

I have a very small knowledge about grammar or syntactic analysis, so probably you, with more knowledge, could find ways of make it simpler or do "smarter calculations".

I took the freedom to write it in ES6-ish style, if reduce is a strange animal for you, [you can read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) or use the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#reduce) / [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce) / whatever ^^

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll study it tomorrow in detail, and anecdotically yes the new function syntax is still hurting my eyes a bit but I'll have to get used to it anyway ;-)

Comment: I didn't use `Array.reduce` so far but it's very fitting here. Also, structures in an array? I had discarded that approach because 1) a literal array will be *massive* 2) this part of the calculation is far from the most cumbersome. The biggest hurdle seems in the next part, iterating over each structure. I'm more and more tempted by another approach, which is determining the *most complex* structure and ignore all others. The order of magnitude itself is the only relevant info here, and the loss in precision in doing that would in fact be a non-issue.

Comment: But thanks a lot for having spent time on my little struggles, the back-and-forth with you here has helped me reclarify and reconsider the overall reasonning. Deserved bounty. Take care.

Comment: Ah, I didn't thought about the possibility of reducing the calcs because of the over grow of one of the calculations... Still, I think you at least should know how big it is and how big is it in comparison with the other structures... Because I dont think you can ignore the number of sentences of the longest structures. I understand about the array with structures, but you could find ways of simplifying them with sets ( verbs * object === objects * verbs), so you save several calcs... But I am glad it helped you! Hopefully you get good results